# I want to match a column from one table with another table and replace those matching values

Tags: r

i have a table say,Table A :

```
uid pid code
1     1  aaa
2     1  ccc
3     4  ddd 
4     2  eee
```

i have another table, Table B:

```
pid msg
1   good
2   inspiring
3   thing to wtch
4   terrible
```

now, i want to replace pid in table A with msg in Table B.

I used `merge(tableA, tableb, by =c("pid"))`

I got the result as

```
uid pid code msg
1    1  aaa  good
2    1  ccc  good
3    4  ddd  terrible
4    2  eee  inspiring
```

where in i want the result as

```
uid msg code
1   good aaa
2   good ccc
3   terrible ddd
4   inspiring eee
```

Comment: You want to eliminate `pid` from the output and reorder the columns?

Comment: I agree with @Henry . Can't you just delete the column `pid` ? `df$pid <- NULL` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach seems absolutely correct, just needs further steps:

1. selection of required columns
2. reordering them

With `tidyverse` functions, you can do something like:

```
TableA %>%
  left_join(TableB) %>%
  select(uid, msg, code)
```

which gives:

```
  uid       msg code
1   1      good  aaa
2   2      good  ccc
3   3  terrible  ddd
4   4 inspiring  eee
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
newtable = merge(tableA,tableB,by = "pid")
newtable$pid = NULL
newtable = newtable[order(newtable$uid,decreasing=FALSE),c(1,3,2)]
```